# How to identify a I2C display controller

Tags: display, i2c, lcd

I have a I2C display from a broken car radio device, I want to use it on my own device.
The display is working because I have some i2c traces before the radio totally dies, with this data I only know how to set memory offset and turn on/off segments, so basically is working, in fact, I'm able to display text, but I have a problem that from time to time the i2c bus got stuck writing to the display, so, I have to disable and re-enable the display with the enable pin (named by me, maybe is a reset pin), to do this I have to put a watchdog on my system because it hangs on isI2CAck.

I need some kind of help to identify the controller on this display, I already check some datasheets but none of them match this display commands, the inscriptions on the backside got no results searching on the net, and I can't see anything on the display glass (sometimes, there are some codes between the glasses, but nothing in this one).

**Segments:** 256 (memory positions 32bytes*8bits, 249 on the crystal)

**I2C Addr:** 0x70

**Pinout** (front view, no pin number, Left to Right): Vcc, Gnd, Gnd, Enable, SCL, SDA

**From radio i2c dump**

Init:

```
    I2CAddr, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    I2CAddr, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x03
```

Set memory position:

```
    I2CAddr, 0x00,  0xDC, position (0-31)
```

Set memory data:

```
    I2CAddr, 0x40, data, data, data, ...
```

**Found by myself**

Some kind of blink:

```
    I2CAddr, 0x00, 0xC0, 0xFn   //n= 0 blink off, 1 blink fast, 2 blink faster
```

Some kind of contrast or pump charger:

```
    I2CAddr, 0x00, 0xC0, 0xC8           *Low contrast, 0xC8 or 0xD8*
    I2CAddr, 0x00, 0xC0, 0xCC           *High contrast, 0xCC or 0xDC*
```

Some kind of recover or a Soft reset:

```
    I2CAddr, 0x00, 0xC0, 0xE0
```

[Display - All Segments On - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiAds.png)

[Back side of display - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a9NS.png)

Found inscriptions:

8345-LED-B-(A161)130401/ROHS/2*2

B2013050034(?)

132569330

Edit:
The stereo was from a Renault Clio car and is a Read Only device,got nACK when I2CWrite( I2CADDR + 1).

Maybe somebody search for the same display and maybe somebody find another commands.

Comment: http://www.lcdwiki.com

Comment: second from Google https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-led-backpack/changing-i2c-address

Comment: Thank you 0andriy but not what I'm looking for, I know lcdwiki and I know to use google.

Comment: Good for you! Good luck with investigation!